# Xcode suddenly corrupted my xib file

Tags: xcode, macos, xib

Last thing I did with it was adding a checkbox and creating an outlet using assistant view. Since then Xcode doesn't compile my project, gives me this error and I don't know what to do with it...[image: The document "MainMenu.xib" could not be opened. The operation couldn’t be completed. *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a complete clean and rebuild of the project.

Also, does your console log indicate any potential problems?

If that does not work and you have a backup, copy your backup to a new location and see whether you have the same problem.

If none of the above worked, then you just have to copy the xib and associated .m and .h somewhere, delete them from the project. Then re-add them. You can copy and paste the .m and .h but you need to remake the xib from the start then link all the outlets and actions.

Comment: Tried it, didn't help.
No, console log shows the same error.
No, I don't have a backup.

Comment: @Grishka I have edited my answer, see the last paragraph. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll follow this if nothing else helps. In that xib file I had a really complicated layout consisting of window with popover and two NSCollectionViews each with bindings to its own NSArrayController. It would be really difficult to recreate all that from scratch.